# MongoDB 3.0.1 upgrade failed start "socket ... is higher than 1023"

Tags: mongodb, sockets, redhat

System: RedHat 6.2. MongoDB 3.0 working perfectly. Just installed 3.0.1 distribution and failed to start

Got:
socket 3832 is higher than 1023; not supported.
Mongodb is exiting

Here are my limits:

- open files: 65000
- file locks: unlimited
- max memory size: unlimited
- file size: unlimited
- virtual memory: unlimited
- max user processes: 65000

Any advice for solving that?

Regards

Comment: Maybe you can set which socket it uses somewhere?

Comment: Are you using mmap or WiredTiger storage engine? Also, what are your command line options for `mongod`?

Comment: There are a few reports of this with 3.0.1 on Linux so I've raised a server issue to investigate: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17652. It would be helpful if you can share a gist/pastebin including the startup information in your mongod log file for more context.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mongod --upgrade` or restart the server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11712945)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. I face the same issue, when I installed the newer version of mongodb while service is running. Why this can't be an answer?